# Jquery check if first td element in table row contains a link

Tags: jquery

Having a Jquery object - table row, how can I find out if the first  element in table row (tr) contains a link?

sample html:

```
<tr class=""><td class=""><p><a>some link</a></p></td><td class="pos">AG</td><td class="size">5.1 MB</td><td class="options"><a class="tip" href="/Packages/View/2">View</a></td></tr>
```

VS:

```
<tr class=""><td class=""><p>no link here</p></td><td class="pos">AG</td><td class="size">5.1 MB</td><td class="options"><a class="tip" href="/Packages/View/2">View</a></td></tr>
```

having a jquery object "row" I tried this without any luck:

```
 var firstTdLink = row.find("td:first a")
if (firstTdLink.length)
{
 alert("first td contains link")
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's a problem with the way you're assigning `row` because your code works fine - see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the following:

```
row.find('td:first-child:has(a)');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
if($("tr td:first > a").length>0)
{
   alert("first td contains link")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original code works fine for me:

```
<table>
<tr class=""><td class=""><p><a>some link</a></p></td><td class="pos">AG</td><td class="size">5.1 MB</td><td class="options"><a class="tip" href="/Packages/View/2">View</a></td></tr>
<tr class=""><td class=""><p>no link here</p></td><td class="pos">AG</td><td class="size">5.1 MB</td><td class="options"><a class="tip" href="/Packages/View/2">View</a></td></tr>
</table>

<script>
console.log( $('table tr:first-child').find("td:first a").length )
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the direct descendent selector:

```
if($('tr td:first > a').length > 0)
{
    alert("first td contains link")
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference in this case versus just `$('tr td:first a')`

Answer (score 0):

I think this way:

```
var firstTdLink = $("td:first").find('a');
if (firstTdLink.length > 0){
  alert("first td contains link")
}
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the OP's code except it doesn't restrict it to a particular row...also it could be more concise: `$("td:first a")` but anyway I think the idea of starting with a particular `row` variable was important...